# Polish chars cant be inserted to DB via jdbc MYSQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jboss

i have a problem with inserting data with polish chars to Mysql DB. Im working on windows 8 and Ubuntu. At Windows there is no problem but on ubuntu i can not insert that kind of chars: "żąśźćłż" in place of them i get: "?????". I have checked with TRACE lvl of logging. My application put correct Strings to prepared query but in db i see  "???????". I can insert that kind of chars via cmd and its ok, so problably there is some problem with connector? Or some other settings. I have tried change:

```
mysql> show variables like "collation%";;
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

to

```
utf8_general_ci
```

every where but after service(mysql) restart its come back with the same with

```
mysql> show variables like "character%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I can not set utf8 for database and server. 
Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: I just put `character_set_server = utf8` in the `[mysqld]` section of my.ini and restarted the MySQL server. Worked for me. (MySQL 5.6.13)

Comment: @GordThompson Could You add this comment ^^ as Answer? I m not able to mark it as GREAT Answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line

```
character_set_server = utf8
```

in the [mysqld] section of the MySQL configuration file (my.ini or my.cnf) should set the new value the next time the MySQL server is started.